# How to retrieve cells or rows with certain condition that may not be adjacent in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find rows from a range with a certain condition (cells from a col are blank) in a more efficient way than what I'm doing now.

Currently, I'm iterating through all the lines of the table range and verifying one by one if they match the condition. Just like this:

```
For Each row in Range("range_name").Rows

    If row.cells(1, 3).Value = "" Then

        ' Do something here...

    End If

Next row
```

However, it would be nice if there was a sort of function that filters out the range and returns the rows with the given condition. Or even something similar.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: [`Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells)? This depends on whether they're truly blank or if for example they contain a formula returning `""`.

Answer (score 0):

Efficiency comes from reducing the number of times your code has to interact with the worksheet.

I think it would be more efficient to read the entire range into an array (thus putting it in memory), and then perform your logic on the values for each row in the array rather than accessing the range each time.  If it's a large range, that can make it run noticeably faster.

If you are changing values in the range, you can make the changes in the array, and then write the array back to the range in one step.